# Скрытие дочернего элемента

Tags: css

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть блок. При наведении на него, скрывается блок внутри (`opacity: 0`). Но при наведении на дочерний элемент, он скрывается тоже. Как сделать, что бы при наведении на дочерний элемент, он не скрывался?

```css
.parent { 
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
.parent-children { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.parent:hover .parent-children {opacity: 0}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого подойдёт селектор `:not` с `:hover`

```css
.parent { 
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
.parent-children { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.parent:hover .parent-children:not(:hover) {opacity: 0}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Его можно перебить равнозначным правилом объявленным после.
Это значит что `.parent-children:hover {opacity: 1}` работать не будет, а более точный `.parent .parent-children:hover {opacity: 1}` сработает.

```css
.parent { 
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
.parent-children { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.parent:hover .parent-children {opacity: 0}
.parent .parent-children:hover {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-children"></div>
</div>
```